# I make a register api and i use it return a authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

i have this code to register but when i register return this.
`{detail: "authentication credentials were not provided"}` 
and this my code please need help to deal with my whole app

```
class RegisterApi(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save(request=self.request)
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        })
```

and here the two serializers class

```
# User Serializer


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "username", "email")


# Register Serializer

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "username", "email")
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            data["username"], data["email"]
        )
        user.set_password(data["password"])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Superuser and login to admin section and call your api.This is work i think.

```
Python manage.py Createsuperuser
```